# Create Function ERROR: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SELECT'

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am new to using CREATE FUNCTION.  So, I am trying to use it atop a working query to change results to UPPER/lower case.  Here is original working query.

```
SELECT 
CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('MCDONALD', cust_name) = 0
    THEN REPLACE(REPLACE([cust_name],'.',''),'--','-')
    ELSE 'MCDONALDS'
END  cust_name
FROM job,dbo.cust cust_name
WHERE job.cust_id_bill_to = cust_name.cust_code AND
job.job_id = '44239' AND
job.sub_job_id = ''
```

Wnen I try to add the CREATE FUNCTION atop this and I get an error, is this the right way to use the function?  Am I wrong altogether?  Or am I close with some tweaks in my syntax?  PLEASE HELP.  Here's my existing query and function, with error.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.InitCap (@inStr VARCHAR(8000))
RETURNS VARCHAR(8000)
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @outStr VARCHAR(8000) = LOWER(@inStr),
     @char CHAR(1), 
     @alphanum BIT = 0,
     @len INT = LEN(@inStr),
             @pos INT = 1;        

-- Iterate through all characters in the input string
WHILE @pos <= @len BEGIN

  -- Get the next character
  SET @char = SUBSTRING(@inStr, @pos, 1);

  -- If the position is first, or the previous characater is not alphanumeric
  -- convert the current character to upper case
  IF @pos = 1 OR @alphanum = 0
    SET @outStr = STUFF(@outStr, @pos, 1, UPPER(@char));

  SET @pos = @pos + 1;

  -- Define if the current character is non-alphanumeric
  IF ASCII(@char) <= 47 OR (ASCII(@char) BETWEEN 58 AND 64) OR
  (ASCII(@char) BETWEEN 91 AND 96) OR (ASCII(@char) BETWEEN 123 AND 126)
  SET @alphanum = 0;
  ELSE
  SET @alphanum = 1;

END

RETURN @outStr;         
END

SELECT 
dbo.InitCap (CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('MCDONALD', cust_name) = 0
                THEN REPLACE(REPLACE([cust_name],'.',''),'--','-')
                ELSE 'MCDONALDS'
           END)  cust_name
FROM job,dbo.cust cust_name
WHERE job.cust_id_bill_to = cust_name.cust_code AND
job.job_id = '44321' AND
job.sub_job_id = ''
```

> RESULT = ERROR: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SELECT'.
>   Error Code: 156

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need to put a `GO` after your `END` and before your `SELECT`.  The `CREATE FUNCTION` needs to be its own separate batch.

Comment: Added GO there.  ERROR: Incorrect syntax near 'GO'.
Error Code: 102   Thats why it had been removed because it was making an error.  Must be something in that area there.  Am I not creating or handling off a variable or something to make the SELECT work right?

Comment: Should @Outstir be incorporated to my SELECT somehow?  I am good at very basic queries and just can't piece this together properly.  Too Complex for my skill level right now.

Comment: First try just creating the function in a SQLPLUS session without invoking your SELECT statement.. see if that succeeds.. then try executing your SQL statement.. since you need to execute the CREATE FUNCTION only once while the SELECT can be executed many times later..

Comment: Ran the function alone and got this.  ERROR: CREATE FUNCTION permission denied in database 'MYDATA'.
Error Code: 262

Comment: Ran the SELECT alone and got this error: ERROR: Cannot find either column "dbo" or the user-defined 
function or aggregate "dbo.InitCap", or the name is ambiguous. 
Error Code: 4121     -   SO looks like its my credentials and otherwise this may all work?  Is that right?

Comment: IF THATS THE PROBLEM, can't I just use it in the query without creating a function.  Can you help me format it to work inline in the query without a CREATE FUNCTION..